# How to only route one app's traffic through the VPN?

Tags: vpn

How to route **only chosen app's traffic through the VPN and make sure it doesn't connect outside of the VPN**? There are two use cases:

- Apps not available in my country (for example Pandora) which I would like to use nonetheless and not accidentally burn/flag my account by revealing the real connection source.
- Similar but for a browser. I would like to have a dedicated browser (maybe Brave) for connecting to some sites. Kinda like Tor Browser but without the hassle, slowness, and suspicion associated with Tor.

I do this successfully on the desktop by running a Mullvad VPN but only routing 10.0.0.0/8 through it and setting the browser to use the [SOCKS5 proxy](https://mullvad.net/en/help/socks5-proxy). This neatly routes only that browser's traffic through Mullvad while at the same time simply failing (kill switch) when the VPN is not active.

On Android, Mullvad app supports ["split tunneling"](https://mullvad.net/en/help/split-tunneling-with-the-mullvad-app) which does the inverse of what I want. It allows to choose apps which are *not* routed through the VPN while all others are.

Comment: Web Browser is simple: there are multiple web browsers like Opera available with built in VPN just for the browser itself.

Comment: @Robert This is kinda like the Tor browser. I would prefer an arbitrary VPN and Mullvad in particular currently.

Comment: Then just use a VPN app that supports "per app VPN" with app whitelisting (in difference to app blacklisting done by Mullvad).

Comment: @Robert which apps offer that mode?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like there are similar questions already: [How to VPN only a single application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22959/44325). Does it help?

Comment: @DamnTerminal Sorry I don't know, just use the correct name of the Android feature to search for it or open a question on our sister site [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) as asking for app recommendations is off-topic here.